# Use of "better still" in two ways

Tags: word-usage, sentence-construction, phrase-usage, vocabulary

I found on Internet that "better still" is used when someone makes a good suggestion,  but you have an even better one. As in this sentence:

> You can send them your resume or better still, try contacting the manager directly.

And Cambridge dictionary defines the meaning as: "even more satisfactory"

I am confused, is "better still" only used to make suggestion or can it be used in other way? For example in the following sentence the phrase has been used according to the meaning given in the Cambridge dictionary.

> That act of kindness is a cherished memory in our hearts better still it is growing as many times it has encouraged us to offer others something beyond their expectation.

Are both meanings and sentences right?

Comment: Hi - asking for grammar to be checked is off-topic on this site. If you can explain why you think it may be wrong and include any research you did then you might just have a question.

Comment: I have edited it and added all my research as well. I am confused for the usage of the phrase because there are two different explanations for the phrase.

Comment: But both definitions mean the same; that the second thing mentioned is better than the first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the second sentence you have posted doesn't use 'better still' right. It should be:

> That act of kindness is a cherished memory in our hearts. Better still, it is growing as, many times, it has encouraged us to offer others something beyond their expectation.

You would use 'better still' just like 'even more satisfactory'. Such as:

> "A Toyota is nice but a Ferrari is even more satisfactory."

> "A Toyota is nice but a Ferrari is better still."