# Two different meanings of "better still" and use

Tags: word-usage, phrase-meaning, difference, phrase-usage

I found on Internet that "better still" is used when someone makes a good suggestion, but you have an even better one. As in this sentence: You can send them your resume or better still, try contacting the manager directly.

And cambridge dictionary define the meaning as: even more satisfactory

I am confused, is "better still" only used to make suggestion or can it be used in other way? For example in the following sentence the phrase has been used according to the meaning given in the cambridge dictionary.

"That act of kindness is a cherished memory in our hearts better still it is growing as many times it has encouraged us to offer others something beyond their expectation."

Are both meanings and sentences right?

Comment: It simply means 'What I am about to mention is even better than the thing I have just mentioned'.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because you have simply copied and pasted [your previously closed question](https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/293700/130147) and have not added any details. If you feel the original question should be opened you should edit it. Do not ask the same question twice.

Comment: I have edited it there as well. The original question was different

Comment: I have added all my research in the edited version.

Comment: I have upvoted your answer. It does seem helpful to me.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Use of "better still" in two ways](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/293700/use-of-better-still-in-two-ways)

Answer (score 1):

Basically ‘better still’ is very similar to even better. It’s really just a more elegant way of saying it. It’s used in a comparative way.

I think the dictionary definition is a bit clumsy and has confused you. You were totally right first time.